# Soji and Kore in Picard season 1 and 2

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-picard

I am confused. In season 1 of Picard, Soji learns that she was created by Dr. Soong. In season 2, Picard and his crew travels back in time. (I know it's said to be an alternate timeline but isn't the events taking place around where the time lines diverge?) Anyway it's definitely in the distant past. How come Dr. Soong is there? At first I thought Kore was the same as Soji but are they two different people with the same appearance? If not, how is Kore alive in that time and how could she not know that Soong created her?

Comment: https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/IdenticalGrandson

Answer (score 10):

I believe you are confusing three or possibly four different people:

1. Dr. Adam Soong, geneticist. Creator of Kore. Appears in Picard season 2. He appears to be experimenting with cloning, rapid growth, and curing diseases.
2. Dr. Arik Soong, geneticist. Descendant of Dr. Adam Soong. Appears in ST:ENT. He experiments with genetically augmented humans. In the end, he realizes that humans are too unstable and decides to start working on androids.
3. Dr. Noonien Soong, cyberneticist. Descendant of Dr. Arik Soong. Creator of Data, Lore, B-4, and Juliana Tainer. Appears mostly in the ST:TNG era.
4. Dr. Altan Soong, cyberneticist. Son of Dr. Noonien Soong. Creator of Soji and Dahj. Appears in Picard season 1.

Soji and Dahj are androids, created after the likeness of Kore. Clearly, Kore must have been very important to the Soong family; it seems like this importance has been passed on from father to son over many generations. This also explains how Data could draw a picture of Soji/Dahj long before either of the two was even created.

Answer (score 3):

**Out-of-universe answer:**

In the case of Picard season 2, the creatives behind the camera seemed to have a strong motivation to bring back the old cast (including Brent Spiner), so a character was incorporated into the story who is an ancestor of the Soongs we have seen previously, all played by Spiner. Thus we have a reason to see a familiar face again. This also creates a premise to bring back Isa Briones in a new role (Kore) who can serve as a reference pattern for the future creation of Soji. This plays into the mystery raised in Picard season 1, where Soji/Dahj were apparently created in the image of some unknown person from Data's past.

Comment: "the creatives behind the camera seemed to have a strong motivation to bring back the old cast" – Oh boy, did they ever! (Trying not to spoil the season finale.)

Comment: @JörgWMittag I know exactly what you mean! That scene seemed to just come out of nowhere, to my thinking, doesn't really connect into the rest of the story at all.